# How to select a customer details whose all row values are same?

Tags: mysql

```
name    start_date   end_date                                                
name1   2021-10-15   2021-10-15               
name1   2021-10-16          
name1   2021-10-15   2021-10-02           
name2   2021-10-15   2021-10-14           
name2   2021-10-15   2021-10-27
```

how to write a query  to select name  whose end date in b/w 2021-10-01 and 2021-10-31 and end_date is not blank.

expected result

```
name 2
```

Comment: Assuming that you're storing the date in a string, SELECT * FROM `customer` WHERE DATE(start_date) >= '2021-10-01' AND DATE(end_date) <= '2021-10-31' AND end_date != ""

Comment: This is not working

Comment: what is the datatype of start_date and end_date?

Comment: Date is the datatype

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: it is showing both name 1 and name 2

Comment: Right, your question was very unclear..

Comment: 'end date in b/w 2021-10-01 and 2021-10-31 ' -  you mean where ALL end date in b/w 2021-10-01 and 2021-10-31

Answer (score 0):

You can group and apply a condition to the group with the having clause

```
SELECT * FROM demo3 WHERE (DATE(start_date) >= '2020-10-01' AND DATE(end_date) <= '2021-10-31') or end_date is null group by name having end_date is not null
```